# Retrieving unique HTML form input in Java Servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets

I'm stuck at a crossroads trying to figure out how to address a problem I need to solve.

I have a table (HTML) that looks like this:

```
+----+------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
| id | filename   | uploader | upload_time         | DELETE?  |
+----+------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
|  1 | backup.txt | user1    | 2014-06-10 13:39:41 | [BTN]    |
|  2 | test.txt   | user2    | 2014-06-11 16:57:01 | [BTN]    |
+----+------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
```

The problem comes into play with the last column. When the user clicks a button, I need to determine the row, and send that data to a servlet.

I know how to handle everything in the servlet and beyond, but I don't know how I can send data to the servlet so it knows which button the user clicks on.

Can anyone suggest a good method to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a form for each button, with hidden input that contain the id :

Button 1 :

```
<form action="/yourServlet" method="POST">
   <input name="id" type="hidden" value="1">
   <input type="submit" value="delete 1">
</form>
```

Button 2 :

```
<form action="/yourServlet"  method="POST">
   <input name="id" type="hidden" value="2">
   <input type="submit" value="delete 2">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Give each button A special name: `TopButton` and `BottomButton`.  When `TopButton` is pressed, it will do what you want it to do.  When `BottomButton` is pressed, it will do what you want to do.  You can do this by doing:

```
TopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener {
    public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {    
        System.out.println("The TopButton has been pressed!");    
    }    
});

BottomButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener {    
    public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {  
        System.out.println("The BottomButton has been pressed!");    
    }    
});
```

Comment: Not really a web-based solution, which appears to be what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @DaveNewton you are correct. This appears to be a solution made for Java Frames. Does not relate at all to the question at hand.